# Exporting rows in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to export a number of rows (from different tables- ie, all the related information about an entity - for eg: a Customer) to another DB in Oracle. How do we do this? I am using a windows OS. Please help. 
Thank you all,
Pradeep

Comment: So you want to export say customers 1-100 and any related records like orders, contact addresses etc.?

Answer (score 2):

While connected to database 1 you could also create a database link to database 2 (if you have rights to do so - there were no assumptions on this) and insert to your tables by selecting from your link e.g. like this

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK foo 
CONNECT TO <user> IDENTIFIED BY <password> 
USING '<connect string>';

select * from table1@foo;
```

Further information:

> A database link is a connection
>   between two physical database servers
>   that allows a client to access them as
>   one logical database.

See [Dabtabase links](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm) at Oracle Database Administrator's Guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Oracle's [export and import utilities](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/A97312_01/exp_impt.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give [Data Pump](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/data-pump-overview-084963.html) a try as well (depending on your version).  Many options for moving around data from Oracle -> Oracle dbs

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the SQL*Plus [copy](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b12170/apb.htm#BGBGGEIC) command.  It's not very fast, but it can be very convenient in certain contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's SQL developer tool has the option to export data as insert statements.